# trying to display result on web page from python

Tags: python, flask

test.py

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    from sklearn import tree
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
    
    df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/vacdata.csv")
    df.head()
    X= df.drop('Name', axis='columns')
    y = df['Name']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
    
    model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model = joblib.load('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/vac-recommender.joblib')
    
    predictions = model.predict([[22, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
    print(predictions)
```

i am trying to display the results of trained model which is predicting vaccine name through input by user but i cant seem to display the result.

app.py

```
    import numpy as np
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
    import pickle
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
    app = Flask(__name__)
    model = joblib.load(open('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/vac-recommender.joblib', 'rb'))
    
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('try.html')
    
    @app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
    def predict():
    
        features = [(x) for x in request.form.values()]
        f_features = [np.array(features)]
        prediction = model.predict(f_features)
    
        output = str(prediction)
    
        return render_template('try.html', prediction_text='vaccine: '.format(output))
    
    @app.route('/results',methods=['POST'])
    def results():
    
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        prediction = model.predict([np.array(list(data.values()))])
    
        output = prediction[0]
        return jsonify(output)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

try.html

```
    <div class="container">
                <br>
                <!--Form-->
                <form action = "{{url('/predict')}}" method ="POST" >
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Heart Disease Test Form</legend><br>
                      <div class="card card-body" >
                          <div class="form-group  row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="age">Age</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="gender">Sex</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="gender"  name="gender" required>
                                  <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Option -- </option>
                                  <option value = "1">Male</option>
                                  <option value = "2">Female</option>
                                </select>
                           </div>
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <div class="col-sm">
                            <label for="exang">heart disease</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="heart_disease" name="heart_disease" required>
                              <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Option -- </option>
                              <option value = "0">No</option>
                              <option value = "1">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm">
                            <label for="exang">blood pressure </label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="oldpeak" name="oldpeak" required>
                              <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Option -- </option>
                              <option value = "0">No</option>
                              <option value = "1">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm">
                            <label for="exang">diabetes </label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="oldpeak" name="oldpeak" required>
                              <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Option -- </option>
                              <option value = "0">No</option>
                              <option value = "1">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm">
                            <label for="exang">stroke </label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="oldpeak" name="oldpeak" required>
                              <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Option -- </option>
                              <option value = "0">No</option>
                              <option value = "1">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        
                          
                          <br>
                          <div class="col-sm">
                            <label for="exang">eczema </label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="oldpeak" name="oldpeak" required>
                              <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Option -- </option>
                              <option value = "0">No</option>
                              <option value = "1">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                                  
                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                    <label for="exang">cancer </label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="oldpeak" name="oldpeak" required>
                                      <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Option -- </option>
                                      <option value = "0">No</option>
                                      <option value = "1">Yes</option>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              
                             
                          <br>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Result">
                          </div>
                          
                          <!--Prediction Result-->
                          <div id ="result">
                                <strong style="color:red">{{result}}</strong>
                         </div>
                         </div>
                 </fieldset>
                </form>
                
            </div>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: use ``` instead of ,,, to format code

Comment: what do you get in browser? Do you get error message in console? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `<form>` sends data as `request.form` but you try to get it as `request.get_json()` - don't you get error message?

Comment: what version of `sklearn` do you use? As I know current version doesn't have `sklearn.externals import joblib` and it needs to use directly `import joblib`

Comment: what flask do you use ? it gives error for `url(...)` because it has to be `url_for(...)`

Comment: do you create this code using some tutorial? Check how old is this tutorial - because you use old methods which are not used any more.

Comment: another mistake - `url_for()` needs function's name from line `def predict()` not name from line `router('/predict')` and it means `url_for("predict")` instead of `url_for("/predict")` - without `/`

Comment: I all time checked `def results():` but now I see that all problem is in `def predict():` and you could put code without `def results():`. And in predict you have mistake which can explain all - you forgot `{}` in `vaccine: {}'.format(output)`, Or you should use `vaccine: ' + str(output)`

Comment: 0.20.3 version for sklearn yes the tutorial is a year older that i followed for training data but as for the codes in app.py is a different tutorial i was looking for anyway to bring it on front end python version that im using is 3.7

Comment: max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
['pfizer']
this is the result i get in console when i run it recommends the correct one its the front end i dont know how to display

Comment: I found another problem - you send as `prediction_text=...` but in template you use `{{result}}` - but it should be `{{prediction_text}}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have model to test it but I think all problem is
because you forgot `{}` in `vaccine: {}'.format(output)`.

Eventually you should use `'vaccine: ' + str(output)`.

---

Other problem is that you assign it to `prediction_text=`

```
render_template('try.html', prediction_text='vaccine: {}'.format(output))
```

but in template you use `{{result}}` - but it should be `{{prediction_text}}`